# CI strategy for embedded development - on-hardware or manual-intervention-required tests

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, embedded

We have a bunch of tests and are implementing CI according to git flow, using Jenkins.

Some of these tests require hardware. However, some of those tests can take 4+ hours (or even 24+ hours) to run, and require hardware that we only have 1 or 2 copies of. Some also need to be run at night.

Furthermore, a minority of tests require some limited manual intervention every few hours to swap a chip out.

I know that a common strategy is to make a test slave for the hardware tests. However, if the job takes a day or more, every time something is pushed to a pull request, that will be prohibitively expensive.

Is there a common solution to this problem? Is GitHub Flow possible within these constraints, or am I going to require release branches, and the understanding that master is not guaranteed to be release-ready at any point since it won't have these tests run?

Is there some way to trigger a specific job through GitHub to launch these expensive jobs, so that they are run only if required?

Answer (score 0):

reviewing your branching strategy can be part of the solution.
I would also review my test strategy, I would execute a small set of fully automated and quick tests on master for instance and the whole batch of tests on release branch.